# Multiply table td's by amount in input with ability to keep using the original value

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I have a drinks recipe tool I'm making in Django. I would like the ability to calculate the needed ingredients per serve. For this I have made an input that allows for numbers.
I now want to multiply the ingredient amounts with the selected amount of servings.
Can I store the original value somehow and alway use that?
What would be a good way to approach this?

My html looks like this:

```
            <table class='cocktail_ingredients my-5'>
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                          <h2>
                              INGREDIENTS
                          </h2>
                      </th>
                      <th>
                          <h2>
                              ML
                          </h2>
                      </th>
                  </tr>

                  {% for ingredient in drink.get_ingredients  %}
                  <tr>
                      <td> {% if ingredient.ingredient_rum %} {{ingredient.ingredient_rum}} {% else %} {{ingredient.ingredient_name}} {% endif %}</td>
                      <td id='amount'> {{ingredient.ingredient_amount}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}


              </table>
```

The JS & JQuery i wrote looks like this. I have no experience with JQuery so far so I hope it makes sense what I've done so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var serveAmount = document.getElementById('serves');
    serveAmount.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        if (!$('#serves').val()) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('.amount').each( function() {
                var amount = parseInt($(this).text());
                var serves = $('#serves').val();
                new_amount = amount * serves


                $(this).text($(this).text().replace($(this).text(), new_amount))
            });
        };
    });
});
```

**edit:**
rendered HTML:

```
              <table class='cocktail_ingredients my-5'>
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                          <h2>
                              INGREDIENTS
                          </h2>
                      </th>
                      <th>
                          <h2>
                              ML
                          </h2>
                      </th>
                  </tr>

                  
                  <tr>
                      <td>  Lime </td>
                      <td class='amount'> 25.0</td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                      <td>  Simple Syrup </td>
                      <td class='amount'> 15.0</td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                      <td>  Original </td>
                      <td class='amount'> 60.0</td>
                  </tr>
                  


              </table>
```

Comment: Can you show the *rendered* html rather than `{%...%}`?

Comment: @mykaf good one. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data-attribute to store the original values for the `ingredients` and whenever the value of serving changes get the data-* value and do calculation on that.

***Changes you can do in your django code*** :

```
 {% for ingredient in drink.get_ingredients  %}
  <tr>
    //..some codes.. added data-original --
    <td class='amount' data-original='{{ingredient.ingredient_amount}}'> {{ingredient.ingredient_amount}}</td>
 </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

***Demo Code :***

```js
$('#serves').on('change', function() {
  var serves = $('#serves').val();
  $('.amount').each(function() {
    var amount = parseInt($(this).data('original'));//get data-*
    new_amount = amount * serves
    $(this).text(new_amount.toFixed(1))//add value to td
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='cocktail_ingredients my-5'>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <h2>
        INGREDIENTS
      </h2>
    </th>
    <th>
      <h2>
        ML
      </h2>
    </th>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td> Lime </td>
    <!--added data-*-->
    <td data-original="25.0" class='amount'> 25.0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> Simple Syrup </td>
    <td data-original="15.0" class='amount'> 15.0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> Original </td>
    <td data-original="60.0" class='amount'> 60.0</td>
  </tr>


</table>


<input type="number" id="serves" value="1">
```